# Flutter StreamSubscription cancel() not canceling in Stateless widget

Tags: dart, flutter

I have this Streamsubscription in a Stateless widget

```
StreamSubscription < LocationResult > subscription = 
Geolocation.locationUpdates(
accuracy: LocationAccuracy.best,
displacementFilter: 30.0, // in meters
inBackground: true,)
.listen((result) {
if (result.isSuccessful) {         
saveResult(result);
} else {
}
});
```

I call this in a timer

```
startTimeout(mins) async {
await subscription.resume();
print("susbscription started");
return new Timer(Duration(minutes: mins), handleTimeout);
}
void handleTimeout() async{  // callback function
await subscription.cancel();
print("susbscription canceled");
}
```

The timer is called on button click:

```
startTimeout(1);
```

After a minute susbscription canceled is printed but the Geolocator keeps getting called.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the Geolocator keeps getting called". Does it keep generating *events*, and do you keep receiving them? If so, I'm guessing you are cancelling the wrong subscription - you should not get events after the cancel. If you can see that the server keep getting requests, then there might be a bug in the `Geolocation`'s treatment of canceling, but that's something that is unlikely to pass through testing without getting caught. So, can you explain exactly what you are seeing, and what you expected to see instead?

Answer (score 0):

```
Future cancel ()
```

Cancels this subscription.

After this call, the subscription no longer receives events.

> The stream may need to shut down the source of events and clean up
>   after the subscription is canceled.
>
> Returns a future that is completed once the stream has finished its
>   cleanup.
>
> For historical reasons, may also return null if no cleanup was
>   necessary. Returning null is deprecated and should be avoided.
>
> Typically, futures are returned when the stream needs to release
>   resources. For example, a stream might need to close an open file (as
>   an asynchronous operation). If the listener wants to delete the file
>   after having canceled the subscription, it must wait for the cleanup
>   future to complete.
>
> A returned future completes with a null value. If the cleanup throws,
>   which it really shouldn't, the returned future completes with that
>   error.

Comment: Yeah, I looked this up already, and I do cancel() in the timeOut.